# Updating the Powerpoint Chart Data Using OpenXML

Tags: ms-office, openxml

I am using **OpenXML** to iterate withing my presentation and accessing slide and charts in it.
Is there any way through which I can access a chart by title or by name and just update the data in it just like we do using Powerpoint.Interop

Thanks